# Tally Prime Xml import Voucher total donot match

Tags: tally

I have been trying to import xml to tally which is working fine but when roundoff is there then i get problem like voucher total do not match.
and not for rounding like 102.98 -> 103.00.
it causing problem if there is any amount like 102.38 then i need it to be 102.00, and here i am getting error.

Stackoverflow doesn't allow more than 300 chars so please click on [the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MUJHsNdK1XFuEKgZyqwD_eTorOt6Zdja/view?usp=sharing) to download the xml file

here the first voucher is working fine but 2nd one is cauing the error like

```
Importing Data to company: 'ABC Old'

ERROR: Voucher: ID:<>, Voucher Type: Purchase, Source Voucher Number: 7, Voucher Number: 3, Date: 1-Apr-22
       Voucher totals do not match! Dr: 2,182.09 Dr Cr: 2,182.09 Cr Diff: 0.00 Cr

Import Summary
Created : 1
Altered : 0
Deleted : 0
Combined: 0
Ignored : 0
Errors  : 1
----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: as debit credit difference is 0.00 so why Voucher totals is not matching i don't understand

Comment: Next Time , If you know the Defaulting Voucher, Then Post only XML related to that voucher, Don't post full payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totals Not Matching, If you are using 2 digit decimal round all amounts to 2 digits,

Since some amounts are 3 and 4 point decimal
You will get Debit Total - 2182.0885 and credit Total 2182.09000

Since difference is after 2 decimal ,In error it is show 0.00(Rounding 0.0015 to 2 decimals)
[image]

Comment: Hi @13605609 (Sai Vineeth) thanks a lot. You have exactly pointed out the mistake. Thanks man. It's a great help.